# Is url mapping for unknown query parameters possible in apache / php?

Tags: php, html, apache, mapping

I'm looking to have a path such as

```
https://www.example.com/operation/query1/query2/etc...
```

Live Example:

```
https://www.wowprogress.com/guild/eu/the-maelstrom/Ashbringers
```

All i can think of is GET parameters like `https://www.example.com/operation?query1=val&query2=val&etc...`

I'm quite new to this so have little understanding how this would be possible using just Apache PHP. I know that this can be done in a java servlet application using URL mappings, though is this even possible in Apache PHP? And if so, how would it be done?

Comment: https://serverfault.com/questions/214512/redirect-change-urls-or-redirect-http-to-https-in-apache-everything-you-ever

Comment: I would add that when using rewriting rules, you don't HAVE to rewrite the URL segments to GET parameters, you could just `explode` your URL to get all you need. This is pretty much how Wordpress handles its rewritten URLs, for example.